# Structuring data in firebase from RDBMS perspective

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, nosql

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using firebase for backend. I am used to the traditional relational DBMS and this is my first time trying out the NoSql way. I am having a hard time structuring my data. I am not sure if I am doing it right. 
Here is my domain (defining it in a traditional fashion).

```
User table -
has username
has name
has email
has authentication type - authenticated by facebook or google 
has location {}
has role {}
has many services

location table - (separating this table because i would like to use geofire and it probably needs a separate node in firebase.)
has lat
has long
has userid

role table - 
has role id
has role name

services table
has service id
has service name
has category id

category table
has category id
has category name
```

I created the user using facebook authentication in firebase and this is what got created in firebase

```
myfirebaseio.com/users/
facebook:some-uid {
    email : "a@a.com",
    name : "abc xyz",
    userid : some-uid,
}
```

How can i structure my data in firebase in a good flattened strcuture.
One example of user domain in firebase i could think of is as follows -

```
myfirebaseio.com/users/
    facebook:some-uid {
        email : "a@a.com",
        name : "abc xyz",
        userid : some-uid,
        role : {
            id : id,
            name : "rolename"
        }
        services : {
            id: id,
            name : "service name",
            categoryid : "catid"
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is that I am not sure if I should create all the other tables nodes as well. It will add redundancy.

How do i structure users and services?
A user can provide many different type of services and A service can be provided by many users.

I want to use geofire for location based services - 
For Location, I dont want to store every users location , Only the users with a specific role should
have their location saved. Should i add location object in users node? Can 2 different users node have different attributes?
for user A - i have location set in user.
but for user B - i dont have the location saved in user because the role is different.
Is this a good practice?

It would be great if someone can suggest a good data structure for these tables.

Comment: NoSQL data modeling is an incredibly broad topic, well beyond what we can handle here on StackOverflow. I recommend reading this article carefully: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/.

Comment: In general your question is simply too broad to answer on StackOverflow, so I'm going to vote to close it. You're also asking a lot of question in one go. Below is an answer to one of the less subjective questions. I suggest that you read the article I linked, come up with a data architecture for your app, work with it a bit and then when you have a concrete question about that: post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> For Location, I dont want to store every users location , Only the users with a specific role should have their location saved. Should i add location object in users node?

No. With Geofire the geolocation separate from the other data about the object.

An example:

```
/locations
    user1
        g: "pns0h0mf2u"
        l: [-53.435719, 140.808716]
    user2
        g: "u417k3dwub"
        l: [56.83069, 1.94822]
/users
    user1: ...
    user2: ...
    user3: ...
```

In this JSON snippet `locations` holds the data that Geofire queries, while `users` holds the other data for each user.